# Indirect method calling without an helper variable

Tags: perl

Have this working short code

```
use 5.014;
package Module;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use Method::Signatures::Simple;

has 'commands' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub{{
        open   => 'my_open',
        close  => 'my_close',
    }},
);

method run($cmd, $args) {
    my $met = $self->commands->{$cmd} if exists $self->commands->{$cmd};
    $self->$met($args) if $met;

    #-----
    #how to write the above two lines in one command?
    #the next doesn't works
    # $self->commands->{$cmd}($args) if exists $self->commands->{$cmd};
    #-----
}

method my_open { say "module: open" }
method my_close { say "module: close" }

package main;
my $ef = Module->new();
$ef->run('open');
```

The main question is in the code - how to write in one line the "run" method - without the helper variable `$met`.

And, is here better way to do the above scenario - so calling methods based on input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please don't do `my $foo = $x if $y`. You get unexpected and undefined behavior, so it is best to avoid that syntax.

The piece of code

```
my $met = $self->commands->{$cmd} if exists $self->commands->{$cmd};
$self->$met($args) if $met;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (my $met = $self->commands->{$cmd}) {
  $self->$met($args);
}
```

because the `exists` test is superfluous here (an entry can only be true if it exists).

If we do not wish to introduce another variable, we have two options:

1. Trick around with `$_`:

   ```
   $_ and $self->$_($args) for $self->commands->{$cmd};
   ```

   This uses the `for` not as a loop, but as a topicalizer.
2. Trick around with scalar references:

   ```
   $self->${\( $self->commands->{$cmd} )}($args) if $self->commands->{$cmd};
   ```

   or

   ```
   $self->${\( $self->commands->{$cmd} || "no_op" )}($args);

   ...

   method no_op { }
   ```

   Don't do something like this, because it is impossible-to-read line noise.

Neither of these is particularly elegant, and it would be better to use the cleaned-up solution I have shown above.

Just because something *can* be done in a single line does not mean it *should* be done. “*This is Perl, not* … oh, nevermind”.

Comment: @Nemo `my` has two effects: (1) At compile time, it introduces a lexical variable into the current scope. (2) At run time, `my` initializes a new variable to `undef` (or something along these lines). Things start to get weird when the variable is introduced, but isn't initialized. Historically this has been used to mimick `state` variables before perl 5.10. If you ask this as another question, somebody with more chickens on his head might provide a better explanation – I don't quite know the specifics here.