# What is wrong in "my $foo = $x if $y" syntax?

Tags: perl

In my last question here, @amon gave [an great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20176876/771480).  However, he told too:

> First of all, please don't do `my $foo = $x if $y`. You get unexpected
>   and undefined behavior, so it is best to avoid that syntax.

Because the above construction I was see in *really many* sources in the CPAN, I'm wondering how, when, where can be it wrong. (Some example code would be nice). Wondering too, why perl allows it, if it is bad.

Comment: can you give examples of such modules?

Comment: @mpapec: try a search on http://grep.cpan.me

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161111

Answer (score 13, accepted):

His wording was actually a bit laxer. That wording is actually mine. Let's start with the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html): (Emphasis in original)

> **NOTE:** The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...`) is **undefined**. The value of the `my` variable may be `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

To be more precise, the problem is using a lexical variable when its `my` may not have been executed.

Consider:

```
# Usage:
#   f($x)  # Store a value
#   f()    # Fetch and clear the stored value

sub f {
   my $x if !@_;
   if (@_) {
      $x = $_[0];
   } else {
      return $x;
   }
}

f('abc');
say "<", f(), ">"   # abc
```

This is obviously not the documented behaviour of `my`.

> Because the above construction I was see in really many sources in the CPAN

That code is buggy. If you want a value to persist between calls to a sub, you can use a `state` variable since Perl 5.10, or a variable outside of the sub.

Comment: I wonder whether perl's behavior should be seen as problematic (say: buggy) here, and perl should be fixed (i.e. to parse such code as `my $foo; $foo = $x if $y`).

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, Consider `my $x = $x if ...;`

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, Honestly, `my $x = ... if ...; ... $x ...` simply makes no sense.

Comment: I was surprised this wasn't a warning already (even if this would annoy certain morons who use fatal warnings…). It seems that one would just have to look for the Opcode pattern `and(*, sassign(*, padsv:LVINTRO))` (where `*` is the whatever star). Plus the same for `or`. Where would such a checker be implemented?

Comment: @amon, it's a bit tricky. `f() && (my $x = g());` is a problem, but  `f() && (my $x = g()) or die;` isn't.

Comment: @amon At least http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Variables/ProhibitConditionalDeclarations.pm exists.

Comment: @ikegami Just try `perlcritic --quiet -s Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations /usr/perl5.18.1/lib/` — I think the language has to be really fixed here.

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, That `perlcritic` command didn't give a warning for `f() && (my $x = g());` or for `f(my $x) if $y; g($x);`.

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, Keep in mind that it shouldn't warn for `{ f(my $x) if $y; }`. It's really not that simple. You don't seem to know what you're talking about.

Comment: @ikegami I don't know what your point is. Don't you agree that `my $foo = $x if $y` is a dangerous construct? And if it is, then a user should be warned about, or the language changed to be more DWIMish?

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, It should give a warning or even an error *when used wrong*.