# Uses and alternatives for the “my $foo = $x if $y” syntax?

Tags: perl

ikegami's comments to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177827/what-is-wrong-in-my-foo-x-if-y-syntax) imply that there is a correct usage of this or similar constructs.  Can someone explain what that usage might be and why someone might want to use it?  I already know about the use of scoping to create stateful variables in all versions of perl and about state variables in more recent versions of perl.

Also, I'm really tired of writing:

```
my $foo;
$foo = $x if $y;   # $foo is now undef or $x depending on $y
```

instead of what I wish would work:

```
my $foo = $x if $y;   # DO NOT USE
```

Is there a better (i.e. short, one-line) way that doesn't repeat the variable name?

Comment: It's a strange thing to want to do. I've never thought that it's something I wanted to do in Perl. I would suggest that maybe you need to control your code flow according to the value of `$y`, rather than just controlling the value of `$x` with it. If you show some real code where you wish you could use this construct then I'm sure we could help you better

Comment: `my $foo = $y ? $x : ();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

```
my $foo = $y ? $x : undef;
```

Possibly also

```
my $foo = $y && $x;
```

however this will give any *false* value of `$y` (for example `0` or `""`) to `$x` as well, not only `undef`.

Comment: @dev-null: I don't see how that's relevant

Comment: This is the right answer (I like the formulation from @Сухой27 slightly better).  But I don't like it:  When $y is long and $x is short, I want to say `$foo = $x if $y` so that $y comes at the end, where it won't overshadow $x.  But I don't want to use a separate statement just to declare $foo.