# Conditional initialization/definition of variable

Tags: perl

Can I define a variable only if a parameter is false?
I have something like:

```
my $object = Class::create($args);  
for my $i (@input) {  
  if ($test) {  
     # print some info here     
    next;  
  }   

#use of $object here    
}
```

If I do  something like:

```
my $object = Class::create($args) unless ($test);
```

is that a correct approach for the initialization?

Comment: `my $object = !$test && Class::create($args);`

Comment: @Сухой27: To be honest that is very hard to understand exactly what's going on (at least for me)

Comment: @Jim  The `&&` (and `and`) in Perl short-circuit _and return the value_ (not true/false).  So if `!$test` returns a falsey value (the criterion from your code) then the rest of the statement isn't evaluated and `!$test`'s return is assigned to `$object` (presumably `undef`, emtpy string, etc -- depends on how your `$test` is designed).  If, however, `!$test` returns a truthy value _then_ the rest goes.  This implements the 6 lines from your example, correctly.  Note that mob's answer has the advantage of setting `$object` specifically  to `undef` (and not relying on return from `!$test`).

Comment: @Сухой27: I considered that one, but it defined `$object` and sets it to the empty string on failure, which may or may not be a problem

Comment: @Jim  **Correction** to my long comment above -- the `!$test` returns an empty string if `$test` is truthy.  That **doesn't** "_depends on how your `$test` is designed_" and it cannot return `undef`.

Comment: @mob since it is object in question I would not be bothered with definedness. Readability on the other hand is completely another issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax is ... [fraught with peril](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177827/what-is-wrong-in-my-foo-x-if-y-syntax).

```
my $object = $test ? undef : Class::create($args);

my $object;
$object = Class::create($args) unless $test;
```

are safer alternatives.